# searchable online opengl documentation

Tags: opengl, documentation

Is there documentation on opengl that is searchable?  The one provided [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/) is inadequate in the sense that I can't do something like ctrl-f "gl_rgb" and get results, since it would only search the names of classes or functions.

Before you tell me to just google it, let me mention that if I did a query for "range python docs" it'll take me directly to pythons documentation for range, but I did a similar query for opengl ("gl_rgb opengl documentation") and only got forum results.

Comment: How about [inurl:http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/ gl_rgb](http://www.google.com/search?q=inurl%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengl.org%2Fsdk%2Fdocs%2Fman4%2F+gl_rgb)?

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm looking for something that I can use for other queries down the line, but this will help in the meantime :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a "large PDF", there is always the OpenGL specification itself. I'm something of an adept in OpenGL, so I can read through the spec and know what it's talking about. But most people probably shouldn't. It isn't very readable.

There is the [OpenGL Wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Main_Page), which being a MediaWiki, is very searchable.

> Before you tell me to just google it, let me mention that if I did a query for "range python docs" it'll take me directly to pythons documentation for range, but I did a similar query for opengl ("gl_rgb opengl documentation") and only got forum results.

That's because "GL_RGB" is not something that is "documented". It is an enumerator. Indeed, the meaning of GL_RGB is different depending on where it is used.

As the [internal format parameter](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format) to glTexImage* functions, it means that the internal format of the texture will be a color format that contains red, green, and blue components (alpha being 1.0), and that the implementation will select the number of bits per channel however it sees fit.

As the [pixel format parameter](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer) to glTexImage*, it means that the pixel data given to the function is color data containing red, green, and blue data, in that specific order. So there can't be a single piece of documentation for "GL_RGB" as it has different meanings.

Python's `range` function is a function. And functions have documentation. Just like OpenGL functions. If you search for "glVertexAttribPointer", you will find documentation for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "site:" feature of google
[Here you go](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=gl_rgb%20site%3ahttp://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I know that this exists, I'm just wondering if perhaps there's a large pdf somewhere with everything (I know, it would be big) of a site that has a search bar in it.  If not, this will have to do.